# Replace only the first instance of a substring in an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

So if you have an NSString that goes:

```
@"My blue car is bigger than my blue shoes or my blue bicycle";
```

I would like a method that replaces only the first instance of blue with green, to produce:

```
@"My green car is bigger than my blue shoes or my blue bicycle";
```

How does one do this?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Assuming the following inputs:

```
NSString *myString = @"My blue car is bigger then my blue shoes or my blue bicycle";
NSString *original = @"blue";
NSString *replacement = @"green";
```

The algorithm is quite simple:

```
NSRange rOriginal = [myString rangeOfString:original];

if (NSNotFound != rOriginal.location) {
    myString = [myString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rOriginal withString:replacement];
}
```

Comment: Another pass with `original = @"then"` `replacement = @"than"` might also be advisable.

Comment: Not my problem if the original string has typos. ;p

Comment: Crashes when `original` is `nil`

Comment: Great for performance when you know there is (at most) only an occurrence of each replace target.

Answer (score 27):

**SWIFT 3 and 4 UPDATE:**

```
extension String 
{
    func stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString(
            target: String, withString replaceString: String) -> String
    {
        if let range = self.range(of: target) {
            return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replaceString)
        }
        return self
    } 
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly in Swift 4.2 as well

Answer (score 14):

A more Swift'y version of the implementations posted here. This one matches the syntax `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` in Swift 5.1

```
extension String {

    func replacingFirstOccurrence(of target: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
        guard let range = self.range(of: target) else { return self }
        return self.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
    }
}
```

An example of usage:

```
let string = "I like bacon, please give me some more bacon!"
let newString = string.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "bacon", with: "meat")
```

Answer (score 10):

Swift 4 version:

```
func replacingFirstOccurrence(of string: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
    guard let range = self.range(of: string) else { return self }
    return replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Swift is useful extends *String* in this way:

```
public extension String {

    func stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString(target: String, withString replaceString: String) -> String {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(target) {
            return self.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: replaceString)
        }
        return self
    }

}
```

In this way you can call wherever:

```
let s = "The red red cat".stringByReplacingFirstOccurrenceOfString("red", withString: "fat")
print(s) // "The fat red cat"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  NSString *initialString = @"My blue car is bigger then my blue shoes or my blue bicycle";
  NSRange range = [initialString rangeOfString:@"blue"];
  NSString *replacedString = [initialString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"green"];
  NSLog(@"replacedString: %@", replacedString);
```

Comment: This will fail with an exception if `initialString` does not contain `@"blue"`.

Answer (score 0):

First locate the substring, and then make the replacement. Example :

```
NSString *aString = @"foo bar foo";
NSRange firstFooRange = [aString rangeOfString:@"foo"];
NSString *anotherString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"foo"
                                                             withString:@"bar"
                                                                options:0
                                                                  range:firstFooRange];
```

[NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) documentation.

Comment: Using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` is unnecessary here, because in `firstFooRange` is only one single occurrence.
Use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*) replaceFirstOccuarnceFromString: (NSString*)input withOriginal:(NSString*) original AndReplacment:(NSString*)replacement
{
    NSRange rOriginal = [input rangeOfString: original];
    if (NSNotFound != rOriginal.location) {
        input = [input
                    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange: rOriginal
                    withString:                         replacement];
    }
    return input;
}
```