# Swift String Extension to replace first characters without occurrence

Tags: ios, string, swift

I'd like to replace a character in my string but only the first occurrence of the character.

I'm using this string extension ! but it's replacing all the occurrences

```
extension String {

    func replace(target: String, withString: String) -> String
    {
        return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(target, withString: withString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean without recurrence? Can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33822186/2442804

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the range, so this way you can find only the first

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
var strnigToReplace = "l"
var stringToReplaceTO = "d"

if let range =  str.rangeOfString(strnigToReplace) {
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(strnigToReplace, withString: stringToReplaceTO, options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: range)
}
```

This will find the first occurrence of the character and will limit the replacement to the range of this string.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this function similar to shannoga but as a `mutating` extension on `String`. This way you don't need to create a new copy, you can just modify a `var`.

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceFirstOccurrence(original: String, with newString: String) {
        if let range = self.rangeOfString(original) {
            replaceRange(range, with: newString)
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var testString = "original"
testString.replaceFirstOccurrence("o", with: "O")
print(testString)
```