# How to remove the first space from the NSString?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, whitespace

**I want to remove only first space in below string.**

`NSString *str = @"IF_Distance (GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)";`

> Note: There is a space after IF_Distance and another space after
>   GET_Mi. I am unable to remove the space after IF_Distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace only the first instance of a substring in an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608346/replace-only-the-first-instance-of-a-substring-in-an-nsstring)

Comment: Check the answer in that question.

Comment: *I want to remove only first space in below string.* The solution is obvious and quite simple: `str = @"IF_Distance(GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)"` ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can remove first space by using following code:

First find space by using `rangeOfString:` and then remove by using `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` method.

Like,

```
NSString *str = @"IF_Distance (GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)";
NSString *strSpace = @" ";

NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:strSpace];
NSString *strFinal;

if (NSNotFound != range.location) {

     strFinal = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rangeOfString:` to locate the first space, then use `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` to replace it with the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space by using below code.

```
NSString *str = @"IF_Distance (GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)";

NSString *secondString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"IF_Distance " withString:@"IF_Distance"];
```

Comment: What if the string is dynamically changing?

Comment: @AnuragSharma This is not the Q. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSString *str = @"IF_Distance (GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)";
NSString *firstStringContainingSpace = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] firstObject];//firstStringContainingSpace = IF_Distance

str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:[str rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",firstStringContainingSpace]] withString:firstStringContainingSpace];
```

Output:
str = @"IF_Distance(GET_Mi mi=km*1.4,STRING1,STRING2)";

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",firstStringContainingSpace]` is pointless. Moreover, separating the whole string by whitespaces while only the first one is relevant, is pointless, too.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for some more universal way - this is the variant of it:

```
- (NSString *)removeWhitespaces:(NSString *)string {

    NSMutableArray * stringComponents = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] mutableCopy];
    NSString * fStringComponent = [stringComponents firstObject];
    [stringComponents removeObject:fStringComponent];

    return [fStringComponent stringByAppendingString:[stringComponents componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
}
```