# How to remove 1 component in a string? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have this string "01:07:30" and I would like to remove the zero in "01" and keep everything else the same. My final string should look like this 
"1:07:30"

Is there a way to do so in Swift? Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you looking for date time format? If so this format `yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s` (`H:m:s` is `hour-minute-second` without `0` prefix)  is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following. This will create a string, check to see if the first character is `0` if it is remove it. Otherwise do nothing.

```
var myString = "01:07:30"
if myString.first == "0" {
    myString.remove(at: myString.startIndex)
}
print(myString) // 1:07:30
```

The final result is the string will now be `1:07:30` instead of `01:07:30`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm best understanding your question, you want to replace the occurrences of "01" with "1" in your string, so you can use regex or the string functionality it self

simply:

```
let searchText = "01"
let replaceWithValue = "1"
let string = "01:07:08:00:01:01"
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: searchText, with: replaceWithValue) // "1:07:08:00:1:1"
```

If you want to replace the fist occurrence only, simply follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33822186/3911553

Comment: This is a great solution if you want to replace all `01` with `1`. My answer assumes it's the first character in the string. Just depends on what the coder wants to do.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieFish, regarding the question it is to remove the zero in "01", he didn't mention the first 'character' or occurrence , at all you should stick with the string matching functionality, adding one more characters at the first definitely will break the solution 

Comment: Won't break it. It truly depends on your workflow and what you want. Both solutions are valid. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to deal with string here is one of many solution:

```
var myString = "01:07:30"
let list = myString.components(separatedBy: ":")
var finalString = ""
for var obj in list{
    if obj.first == "0" {
        obj.removeFirst()
    }
    finalString += finalString.count == 0 ? "\(obj)" : ":\(obj)"
}

print(finalString)
```

Comment: The OP said `My final string should look like this "1:07:30"`. Your solution prints `1:7:30`